# Qml doesn't show https images

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt-creator

I'd like to show image in my dialog with qml-image-element

There is description: "The URL may be absolute, or relative to the URL of the component."

When I set url e.g."[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/c0.21.200.157/988761_10153543946465352_1539860600_n.jpg?oh=0c582d3c8ae23f7171096c52b6e6bf88&oe=55880236&**gda**=1434404001_8eb19dcda3ed70d9856477b8d142749c](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/c0.21.200.157/988761_10153543946465352_1539860600_n.jpg?oh=0c582d3c8ae23f7171096c52b6e6bf88&oe=55880236&__gda__=1434404001_8eb19dcda3ed70d9856477b8d142749c)" dialog doesn't show image

But if I set **http://**fbcdn-..., image shows.
What is problem?

Qt 5.4
output is empty

Comment: You need some `ssl` library to open `https://`. What OS do you use? What error do you get in console?

Comment: I guess that iOS. I faced the same problem with it.